# in R dplyr why do I need to ungroup() after I count()?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, lapply, sapply

When I first started programming in R I would often use dplyr *count()*.

```
library(tidyverse)    
mtcars %>% count(cyl)
```

Once I started using `apply` functions I started running into issues with *count()*. If I simply added *ungroup()* to the end of my *count()*'s the problems would go away.

I don't have any particular reproducibles to show. But can somebody explain what the issue likely was, why *ungroup()* always fixed it, and are there any drawbacks to consistently using *ungroup()* after every *count()*, or after any *group_by()*? Of course I'm assuming I no longer need the data grouped after it's counted or summarized.

```
mtcars %>% count(cyl) %>% ungroup()
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The issues you used to run into were from an old behavior of `count()`.
Up to dplyr 0.5.0, if you did:

```
mtcars %>%
  count(cyl, wt)
```

The result would still be grouped by the `cyl` column. This means, for example, that if you followed it with something like `summarize(mean(am))`, you would have gotten one row for each `cyl` when you may have expected one row overall. The issue would be fixed if you put `%>% ungroup()` after the count.

[This behavior was changed in dplyr 0.7.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/news/news.html) (released in June 2017), such that `count()` preserves the grouping of its input (meaning `mtcars %>% count(wt, cyl)` now returns an ungrouped table). This is likely why you're no longer able to reproduce the problems, and it means you no longer need to do `ungroup()` after a `count()`.

---

Note that you may still need to do `ungroup()` after a `group_by()` and `summarize()`:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, wt) %>%
  summarize(n = n())
```

returns a tibble still grouped by `cyl`:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 3
# Groups:   cyl [?]
     cyl    wt     n
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     4  1.51     1
 2     4  1.62     1
 3     4  1.84     1
 4     4  1.94     1
 5     4  2.14     1
 6     4  2.2      1
 7     4  2.32     1
 8     4  2.46     1
 9     4  2.78     1
10     4  3.15     1
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: `group_by(cyl, wt) ` returns a tibble grouped by `cyl` _**and**_ `wt`.

Comment: @skoh Each call of `summarize` drops one grouping level. Please see the first example here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html#examples